# Check if user is redirected from another page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a `<form>` that sends the user to an external page: `action="http:/example.com/test/test.php"`. The `test.php` on the external page executes an SQL query and sends the user to my internal page `test2.php`. The second page `test2.php` also executes an SQL query and the process gets closed.

I want to perform an check operation in `test2.php`. I only want to run the SQL query if the user is redirected from the external page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `Referer` header with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to see what page they were redirected from. This isn't reliable, though, since people can forge headers, but for the most part, if people are using browsers, you can use this to check if they were redirected.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a URL parameter like http://example.com/test/test.php?redirect=true

Comment: You don't know if the external page will also return `?redirect=true`. I assume the OP has no control over the external page.

Comment: True. I was under the impression that he was sending users between the pages. Your answer is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your form use a cross-domain `action`, perhaps you can have your PHP code use curl to submit the information to the foreign server.  Then your PHP code will know exactly what happened.